# Return records distinct on one column but order by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am building a Rails 3 app with a pretty standard message model. I would like to return the most recently created message records for each unique conversation_id. It seems like a fairly simple task, but I have not been able to code or find a working solution.
Admittedly, I am not super SQL savvy either (as I have gotten by with mainly Active Record queries thus far). Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Sample messages table:

```
| id | sender_id | receiver_id | conversation_id | subject | body | created_at |
| 1  |     *     |      *      |        1        |    *    |   *  |    16:01   |
| 2  |     *     |      *      |        2        |    *    |   *  |    17:03   |
| 3  |     *     |      *      |        1        |    *    |   *  |    18:04   |
| 4  |     *     |      *      |        3        |    *    |   *  |    19:06   |
| 5  |     *     |      *      |        2        |    *    |   *  |    20:07   |
| 6  |     *     |      *      |        1        |    *    |   *  |    21:08   |
| 7  |     *     |      *      |        4        |    *    |   *  |    22:09   |
```

The return I would like to get only the most "recent" message record for each `conversation_id` and ordered by `created_at DESC`:

```
| id | sender_id | receiver_id | conversation_id | subject | body | created_at |
| 7  |     *     |      *      |        4        |    *    |   *  |    22:09   |
| 6  |     *     |      *      |        1        |    *    |   *  |    21:08   |
| 5  |     *     |      *      |        2        |    *    |   *  |    20:07   |
| 4  |     *     |      *      |        3        |    *    |   *  |    19:06   |
```

My original solution in SQLite worked just fine:  `GROUP BY (conversation_id)`. However, apparently that solution is unique to SQLite and does not work with Postgres.

Next, I tried: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (conversation_id) *`. However, this also requires `ORDER BY (conversation_id)` which I do not want. I want to order by `created_at`.

Answer (score 2):

#### `DISTINCT ON`

If you use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564), you need a subquery for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (conversation_id) *
   FROM   message t
   ORDER  BY conversation_id, created_at DESC
   ) sub
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

The order in the subquery must agree with the columns in the `DISTINCT ON` clause, so you must wrap it in an outer query to arrive at your desired sort order.

#### Alternative with `row_number()`

Similar story, you need a subquery as well:

```
SELECT id, sender_id, receiver_id, conversation_id, subject, body, created_at
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY conversation_id
                                ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM   message t
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY created_at DESC;
```

Also probably slower.