# Select all threads and order by the latest one

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Now that I got the [Select all forums and get latest post too.. how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615884/select-all-forums-and-get-latest-post-too-how) question answered, I am trying to write a query to select all threads in one **particular** forum and order them by the date of the latest post (column "updated_at").

This is my structure again:

```
forums                      forum_threads              forum_posts
----------                  -------------             -----------
id                          id                        id
parent_forum (NULLABLE)     forum_id                  content
name                        user_id                   thread_id
description                 title                     user_id
icon                        views                     updated_at
                            created_at                created_at
                            updated_at
                            last_post_id (NULLABLE)
```

I tried writing this query, and it works.. but not as expected: It doesn't order the threads by their last post date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(t.id) t.id, u.username, p.updated_at, t.title
FROM   forum_threads             t
LEFT   JOIN forum_posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
LEFT   JOIN users         u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE t.forum_id = 3
ORDER  BY t.id, p.updated_at DESC;
```

How can I solve this one?

Comment: take the t.id out of your order by

Comment: I can't because of the DISTINCT ON.. get an error message otherwise

Comment: `(column "updated_at")` is ambiguous. Please clarify: `forum_posts.updated_at` or `forum_threads.updated_at`? Going to assume the former for my answer, like in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615884/select-all-forums-and-get-latest-post-too-how) and like your query suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a *single row* per thread and not all rows for all posts.

**`DISTINCT ON`** is still the most convenient tool. But the leading `ORDER BY` items have to match the expressions of the `DISTINCT ON` clause. If you want to order the result some other way, you need to wrap it into a subquery and add another `ORDER BY` to the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id)
          t.id, u.username, p.updated_at, t.title
   FROM   forum_threads      t
   LEFT   JOIN forum_posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
   LEFT   JOIN users         u ON u.id = p.user_id
   WHERE  t.forum_id = 3
   ORDER  BY t.id, p.updated_at DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC;
```

If you are looking for a query **without subquery** for some unknown reason, this should work, too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.id
     , first_value(u.username)   OVER w AS username
     , first_value(p.updated_at) OVER w AS updated_at
     , t.title
FROM   forum_threads      t
LEFT   JOIN forum_posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
LEFT   JOIN users         u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE  t.forum_id = 3
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC)
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC;
```

There is quite a bit going on here:

1. The tables are joined and rows are selected according to `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses.
2. The two instances of the window function `first_value()` are run (on the same window definition) to retrieve `username` and `updated_at` from the *latest post* per thread. This results in as many *identical* rows as there are posts in the thread.
3. The `DISTINCT` step is executed *after* the window functions and reduces each set to a single instance.
4. `ORDER BY` is applied last and `updated_at` references the *`OUT`* column (`SELECT` list), not one of the two *`IN`* columns (`FROM` list) of the same name.

Yet another variant, a **subquery with the window function `row_number()`**:

```
SELECT id, username, updated_at, title
FROM  (
   SELECT t.id
        , u.username
        , p.updated_at
        , t.title
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id
                             ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM   forum_threads      t
   LEFT   JOIN forum_posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
   LEFT   JOIN users         u ON u.id = p.user_id
   WHERE  t.forum_id = 3
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC;
```

Similar case:

- [Return records distinct on one column but order by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282870/return-records-distinct-on-one-column-but-order-by-another-column/23284584#23284584)

You'll have to test which is faster. Depends on a couple of circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `distinct on`:

```
SELECT t.id, u.username, p.updated_at, t.title
FROM   forum_threads             t
LEFT   JOIN forum_posts   p ON p.thread_id = t.id
LEFT   JOIN users         u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE t.forum_id = 3
ORDER  BY p.updated_at DESC;
```

Comment: erm, are you sure you're not getting all threads with a forum_id of 3 AND all of their posts?

Comment: you are right, I'm getting all threads and all of their posts.. but that doesn't help, because I cannot group (or only group by t.id and p.id, which doesn't change anything)