# Using different distinct and order_by values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I would like to use distinct and order_by values in my django rest framework.

However, I would like them to be different values.

My traceback: http://dpaste.com/1G7F8YC

How is this possible with Postgres?

```
class WardrobeListView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in wardrobematch:
                lookup, val = wardrobematch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Analytic.objects
            .filter(like=True,**filters)
            .order_by('-updated',)
            .distinct('product_id',)
            .values('product_id', 'product__name', 'product__brand', 'product__store__store_name', 'product__variation__image__image', 'product__variation__price__price',)
        )

        return Response(qset)
```

Comment: Not possible in the same query level. You need a subquery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24623210/939860

Comment: Could you show my how it is possible for my example?